# Unable to access Host OS localhost in Guest OS using Bridged adapter settings

Tags: localhost, virtual-machine, host

I have a quandary. I develop on my guest OS environment (Ubuntu Virtual machine) and have my **added host entries to my hosts file** in my **HOST OS (Windows)**. For this setting to succeed, I have my Virtual machine settings configured to be served by the **Bridged Adapter**

There is a web program that runs on our Windows environment and is served on localhost:2112 
I need my guest OS to be able to access this but I can't get that to happen for the life of me.

I tried to access 10.0.2.2 in my Guest OS but that yielded 'can't establish a connection to the server @ 10.0.2.2'

I retrieved the IPConfig of my host OS and access them in my Guest OS but I am able to do that either.

Then I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/509627/in-virtualbox-how-can-i-access-host-localhost-from-guest-visual-studio-dev-ser) and I installed SPI Port forward, setup localport to 8888, remote host to localhost, and remote port to 2112, banged in 10.0.2.2:8888 on my guest OS to access but it says

```
'The server at 10.0.2.2 is taking too long to respond'
```

I guess the question is, how do I access a Host OS local site on my Guest OS while maintaining Bridged Adapter settings ?